# Django app deployment in AWS Beanstalk - Error after deployment

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django app deployed to AWS beanstalk. The first version was fine after following the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html).

when I deploy, I get this error on the terminal and my eb status health is Red.

I follow all the instructions but don't know what is the problem.

and the 502 Bad Gateway occure in my page.

> 2020/12/17 15:03:40.884211 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/unifolio-src/bin/python: no such file or directory

Comment: Can you share the printout from `eb logs` of the error / traceback?

Comment: You can consider creating an EC2 instance directly and configure it manually. It may take longer to configure everything you need but in my case was way more consistent. Beanstalk was always giving me errors everytime.